# Find all linked records using self join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table and I am trying to use self join.
I am able to achieve only 50% of the expected results.

```
create table auto_correct(spell varchar(255), ne varchar(255));
insert into auto_correct values ('test', 'testing');
insert into auto_correct values ('adn', 'and');
insert into auto_correct values ('and', 'andru');
insert into auto_correct values ('testing', 'tested');
insert into auto_correct values ('this', 'that');
insert into auto_correct values ('junk', 'delete');
```

| spell | ne |
| --- | --- |
| test | testing |
| adn | and |
| and | andru |
| testing | tested |
| this | that |
| junk | delete |

The word 'test' is linked to 'tested' through 'testing'
The word 'adn' is linked to 'andru' through 'and'
How do I find all such linked records and display along with non-linked rows?

The expected results are:

| spell | ne |
| --- | --- |
| test | tested |
| adn | andru |
| this | that |
| junk | delete |

I have tried this:

```
select b.spell, a.ne 
from auto_correct as a 
left join auto_correct as b on a.spell = b.ne 
where b.spell is not null;
```

returns:

| adn | andru |
| --- | --- |
| test | tested |

The rest of the records where no match is found are missing from above output.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version and the answer by Akina is working. But for the sake of completeness, how will I do this in older version, for e.g. 5.0?

Comment: *how will I do this in older version, for e.g. 5.0?* Stored procedure, iterations, temptable.

Comment: *how will I do this in older version* - simple. Upgrade. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT *
         FROM auto_correct
         WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                            FROM auto_correct ac
                            WHERE auto_correct.spell = ac.ne )
       UNION ALL
         SELECT cte.spell, auto_correct.ne
         FROM cte
         JOIN auto_correct ON cte.ne = auto_correct.spell )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM auto_correct
                   WHERE auto_correct.spell = cte.ne )
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e90235ce5dde96a7255f8afe1a19d334